# FormBorderStyle is none not woking?

Tags: c#

I can not remove the border when using Windows Forms:

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None();
```

Comment: Remove Brackets??

Comment: also please paste the code to make sure your question is relevant

Comment: Is this WinForms? The compiler will give you a helpful message you should not ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Its a property that expects an enum:

```
  this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41(v=vs.110).aspx) for reference